# Stop wicket from reloading page

Tags: wicket

I am working on an existing project with no previous experience in wicket.

The application has a page with four tabs. the first three tab is suppose to reload every 60 sec. The last tab is what I am working on and I don't want it to reload ever. I cannot find out where is the code that does the reloading

When a do a view source of the UI. I see something like this

```
Wicket.Event.add(window, "load", function(event) { 
Wicket.TimerHandles['id135'] = setTimeout('Wicket.Ajax.ajax({\"c\":\"id135\",\"u\":\"./?2-3.IBehaviorListener.0-viewPanel-contentPanel-criticalZonePanel-1\"});', 60000);
Wicket.TimerHandles['id225'] = setTimeout('Wicket.Ajax.ajax({\"u\":\"./?2-3.IBehaviorListener.0-\"});', 60000);
```

Not sure if there is enough hint to figure out what might be causing the reloading or what kind of code or keywork should I be looking for in the application to change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JavaScript is generated by `AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior` or its specialization `AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior`. Check where in your page/tabs any of those is used and disable it for the fourth tab.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find it in the Index page from which all other pages inherit. Is there a way I can disable it inside one of the child panels

Comment: You can either `remove()` it or `stop()` it and later either re-`add()` it or `restart()` it. Check the APIs of those classes.